# When wildcard is used in logs directory, what does the size tell? The size of 1 log or the total size of all the logs?

Tags: nginx, logrotate

https://www.keycdn.com/support/logrotate#maxsize

> This limits each log file's size to the specified number of bytes

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log
{
size 50G
}
```

Does the 50G size here means the size of all the logs in `/var/log/nginx` (example `access.log` `error.log` etc)? Or something else?

I read the https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html man pages but could not figure this out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logrotate rule is applied individually to each matching file - i.e. each file matching `/var/log/nginx/*.log` has its own 50GB limit.